# Writing a complex function, best practices, semantics

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following function:

```
ui->user->setCurrentIndex(ui->user->findText(modelSuppliers->record(index.row()).value(modelSuppliers->record(index.row()).fieldName(5)).toString()));
```

It sets the current index of a drop down menu to the corresponding column on a relational table model when a row on the table is selected.
I just wrote this function and just by looking at it get dizzy. Maybe in a month when i look at this thing i will vomit. How do you handle this kind of declarations. Would you make an intermediate variable to hold some parts of the function, for example

```
QString value=modelSuppliers->record(index.row()).fieldName(5)).toString();
```

and insert the value in the original function? Or you just don't bother?

Comment: That's not a function.

Comment: Use temporary variables and possibly statement blocks.

Comment: Take it apart.  If the function returns a value, assign into a temporary variable.  Use the variable as the parameter to the next function.

Answer (score 0):

The code becomes much easier to read when you decompose it:

```
auto record    = modelSuppliers->record(index.row());
auto fieldName = record.fieldName(5);
auto text      = record.value(fieldName).toString();
auto index     = ui->user->findText(text);

ui->user->setCurrentIndex(index);
```